# RSpec argument contraints for any number of anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mocking, arguments, expectations

How to write correctly the expectation with matching first argument and ignoring other arguments? There can be any number of other arguments.

```
expect_any_instance_of(MyClass).to receive(:my_method).with('Argument', any_args)
```

I got this error:

```
RSpec::Mocks::MockExpectationError: #<MyClass:0x4589d604> received :my_method with unexpected arguments
  expected: ("Argument", any args)
       got: ("Argument", 0, 100, nil)
```

Why does it not matched the arguments?

Could you suggest a custom matcher for this?

Comment: Probably any args works only, if you use it as single param.
Like expect_any_instance_of(MyClass).to receive(:my_method).with(any_args)

Comment: Yep, it seems it started allowing it to be used for sublists in [3.2](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-2/docs/setting-constraints/matching-arguments).